# "They vary mainly in ..." or "They mainly vary in"

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, word-order

I have this sentence

> They **vary mainly** in the degree of automation they provide by reducing human efforts as much as possible.

But as I know adverbs come before the verb, could it be

> They **mainly vary** in the degree of automation they provide by reducing human efforts as much as possible.

If no, what makes the exception here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they vary in several ways (let's say cost, durability, and range of colors) but the greatest variation is in cost:

They vary mainly in cost.

*Mainly* applies to the prepositional phrase complement of *vary*.

Comment: Thank you, could you give a compliment example when "mainly" comes before "vary"?

Comment: The data show that under certain circumstances the efficiency of these two engine designs is similar (both are inefficient at extreme temperatures) but under typical operating conditions, and with the same fuel mixture, the efficiency of the designs mainly varies.